# HTML Tidy && Notepad++ - Unkown Exception

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I am currently installing html tidy from the textfx plugin. The Notepad++ version I am running is 6.2.3. I created the folder Config/tidy in plugins and put the two files(HTMLTIDY.cfg, libtidy.dll) in there.

However, I still get the message "UNKNOWN EXCEPTION!"

I appreaciate your answers!!!

Comment: lol -2 for what?

Comment: I've edited the tags appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

For [**Notepadd++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), this *HTML Tidy* version is a recent *HTML5 W3C* version:

[**A new HTML-Tidy plugin**](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/482781/thread/2eeba3f3/)

The second post states the current version is [**0.2**](https://github.com/downloads/davegb3/NppTidy2/Tidy2_0.2.zip)

Answer (score 0):

I had unknown exception on notepad++ v6.5.5 start. not sure the cause. Just went to plugin manager checked all plugins and reinstalled them. Exception gone.